# What name to use when communicating between AWS subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, networking

I've been googling this all day and can't quite figure it out. I'm trying to setup a multi-tier application in an AWS VPC, but I'm pretty a rookie at large system network architecture. I'm going to be using several subnets to handle different parts of the application. Our app servers will need to communicate with database servers in the DB subnet, as well as various other services in other subnets. I'm going to be using CloudFormation to orchestrate all of this.

My question is very basic. What names/IPs do I configure to my applications with so they can communicate with these other services. My app servers will need a url/IP for the database and all of these other services. I can't seem to figure out a way to assign a hostname to the created resources.

Comment: Have you considered assigning DNS names in Route53?

Comment: Yes, but from what I understand they can only be used for public routes, correct? These would be internal (db.mycompany.com, app.mycompany.com, etc)

Comment: Nope, Route53 records can be for anything. Even CNAMEs to internal names or A's for private addresses.

Comment: @GatorCSE - if you are happy with the answer below please mark it as a correct answer to award the author for the time spent trying to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **database** you've got two options:

1. **RDS** - database managed by Amazon and provided to you as a service. In that case you're given a hostname on the RDS details page. It could be something like `mysql-rds01.abcdefgh.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com` - use that.
2. Roll out your **own DB server** with OS you manage. In that case you can either use the internal name e.g. `ip-172-31-44-105.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal` or better create a zone in *AWS Route53* and in that zone create a record like `db-server` being a `CNAME` pointing to the above name. That has the advantage of using a stable name (`db-server`) that can be updated on a single place (Route53) if the instance IP changes.

Always try to **use RDS** unless you've got a very good reason why not to use RDS and roll your own.

Next, for communicating between tiers it may be a good idea to use **Elastic Load Balancers** (ELB) - they can be *internal*, e.g. hide your internal web services cluster behind an internal ELB and for talking to the web service use the DNS name of the ELB. Will be something like `internal-blahblah-12345678.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com` and again you can give it a nice `CNAME` in *Route53*.

Needless to say all of this will be managed by your **CloudFormation** templates. In the same template that creates your webservice host also create its ELB and its Route53 records. You'll then have all the whole logically related resources created in one go.

Comment: we use internal ELB for accessing machines. Sounds quite dumb to have an ELB sit on top of only one EC2 instance, but it does help because then you can forget about changing IPs and just rely on the DNS name of elb to connect to EC2.